# Should I be using erase-remove idiom here?

Tags: c++, std, erase, erase-remove-idiom

I have an `std::vector<IRenderable*>` (`_pBkBuffer` in the code below).  It contains a number of static objects (at the start of the vector) that don't change, followed by a variable number of dynamic objects.

```
// erase-remove, but leave the static renderables intact
_pBkBuffer->erase( 
    std::remove(
        _pBkBuffer->begin() + _nStatics, _pBkBuffer->end(), ???
    ), 
    _pBkBuffer->end() 
);
```

What can I put at the ??? in order to erase-remove the non-static renderables?

I know that the ??? should match all objects in the specified subset.

Should I be using erase-remove at all, or should I use another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 'Should I be using erase-remove at all

Aparently you already know where the object are, so no. You do this:

```
_pBkBuffer->erase( _pBkBuffer->begin() + _nStatics, _pBkBuffer->end() );
```

or, even better:

```
_pkBuffer->resize( _nStatics );
```

Erase remove idiom would be used if you had them scattered randomly in the vector. What's missing instead of `???` is a value that elements to be removed are compared to. Since you're storing pointers, you'd most likely need to provide a custom predicate (a function pointer, functor, or a lambda) and use [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead.

Comment: thanks.  will accept in 10 mins when I'm allowed :)  I spent all my time looking up the std::remove documentation, I should've looked closer at vector::erase!